# Update records in CakePHP (array format)

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.x

How to save this type of data? It gives me

```
Array to String conversion error.
```

My `asc201516s_teachers` table has the following columns:

- `teachers_name`
- `teachers_cnic`
- `teachers_gender`
- `teachers_contact`.

My data array is:

```
 [asc201516s_teachers] => Array
    (
        [teachers_name] => Array
            (
                [0] => asd asd 
                [1] => asd asd asd 
                [2] => asd asd asd asd 
            )

        [teachers_cnic] => Array
            (
                [0] => 32312-1212121-2
                [1] => 33434-3434343-4
                [2] => 34454-5454545-4
            )

        [teachers_gender] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 2
                [2] => 2
            )            

        [teachers_contact] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1234-5678910
                [1] => 2345-6789101
                [2] => 3456-7891011
            )

    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your form fields like these, you can put the below code in a loop or other alternative way so that you can get the dynamically value of $key variable for ex:0,1,2,3,4.. etc.

```
echo $this->Form->input('modelName.' . $key . '.teachers_name', array());
echo $this->Form->input('modelName.' . $key . '.teachers_cnic', array());
echo $this->Form->input('modelName.' . $key . '.teachers_gender', array());
echo $this->Form->input('modelName.' . $key . '.teachers_contact', array());
```

After submitting the form you can recieve the form in your controller like this way

```
$data=array(
    '0' => array(
        'teachers_name'=>'asd asd',
        'teachers_cnic'=>'32312-1212121-2',
        'teachers_gender'=>'1',
        'teachers_contact'=>'1234-5678910'
    ),
    '1' => array(
        'teachers_name'=>'asd asd asd',
        'teachers_cnic'=>'33434-3434343-4',
        'teachers_gender'=>'2',
        'teachers_contact'=>'2345-6789101'
        ),
    '2' => array(
        'teachers_name'=>'asd asd asd asd',
        'teachers_cnic'=>'34454-5454545-4',
        'teachers_gender'=>'2',
        'teachers_contact'=>'3456-7891011'
    )
);
```

Then you can save the form data, like the below way.

```
$this->Teacher->saveMany($data);
```

If you need more information, Please let me know,
If you find this answer is useful, Please mark this answer as acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to save multiple records in CakePHP 2.x is as follows:

```
$data=array(
    '0' => array(
        'teachers_name'=>'asd asd',
        'teachers_cnic'=>'32312-1212121-2',
        'teachers_gender'=>'1',
        'teachers_contact'=>'1234-5678910'
    ),
    '1' => array(
        'teachers_name'=>'asd asd asd',
        'teachers_cnic'=>'33434-3434343-4',
        'teachers_gender'=>'2',
        'teachers_contact'=>'2345-6789101'
        ),
    '2' => array(
        'teachers_name'=>'asd asd asd asd',
        'teachers_cnic'=>'34454-5454545-4',
        'teachers_gender'=>'2',
        'teachers_contact'=>'3456-7891011'
    )
);

$this->Teacher->saveMany($data);
```

See

- [`Model::saveMany()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savemany-array-data-null-array-options-array)

Comment: It is easy if the array is of fixed indexes. Teachers count can be 150, so how would I set values to this format in a loop ? can you guide me please?

Comment: Just use `array_push($record)` or `$data[]=$record`. However, not sure why you would want to add 150 Teachers at once.